Confusion about Open Sets and Closed Sets
I'm currently reading "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis by George F. Simmons". In this book on points 10 and 11 respectively open and closed sets,

Theorem 10. In any metric space $X$, the empty set $\emptyset$ and the full space $X$ are open sets.

Explanation. To show that $\emptyset$ is open, we must show that each point in $\emptyset$ is the center of open sphere contained in $\emptyset$ but since there are no open points in $\emptyset$, this requirement is automatically satisfied. $X$ is clearly open, since every open sphere centered on each of its points is contained in $X$.

Theorem 11. In any metric space $X$, the empty set $\emptyset$ and the full space $X$ are closed sets.

Explanation. The empty set has no limit points, so it contains them all and is therefore closed. Since the full space $X$ contains all points, it automatically contains its own limit points thus is closed.
Now I'm confused as in one theorem both empty set and $X$ is considered open and in other theorem both are considered closed.

Very simply, a set — unlike a door — can be both open and closed. Note that the definition of a closed set is not that it is not open.

Sometimes such sets, both open and closed,  are referred to as "clopen".

A set can also be neither open nor closed.

Open and closed are not opposites and not incompatible.  In every metric space, the space and the empty set are always both open and closed.  That's not a contradiction.   In the euclidean metric they are the only two sets that are both but in other metric spaces there can be many.  Likewise, there can be sets that are neither.

One thing kind of interesting is that if a set, S, is open then the complement $\overline S = {x\in X| x\not \in S}$ will be closed and vice versa.  In that way they act a little like opposites, but they are not (when applied to the same set) in anyway contradictory.

The confusing terminology has been widely criticized, but it is not going to change.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

It is perfectly possible for a set to be open and closed at the same time (unlike a door, as Ted Shifrin joked in the comments). Such sets are referred to as "clopen" (for "closed open").
In $ℝ^n$ (often the first example of a metric space you encounter), and in many other spaces, the only clopens turn out to be the empty set and the whole space. This property is very important, and spaces that satisfy it are said to be connected.
For an example of a space that is not connected, take the metric space $[0, 1] ∪ [2, 3]$ (with the usual metric). You can check that when viewed as a subset of this space (but not, of course, as a subset of $ℝ$), the sets $[0, 1]$ and $[2, 3]$ are clopen.

An additional example is the following one:
Let $X$ be a set. Define the topology on $X$ induced by the discrete metric ($d(x, y) = 1, \forall x, y \in X \mid x \neq y$, and $d(x, x) = 0, \forall x \in X$). This is a metrizable topological space (called the discrete topology on $X$) and it verifies that the singletons are open ($\{y \in X \mid d(x, y) < 1\} = \{x\}$). Therefore, every subset of $X$ is open aswell and, consequently, every subset of $X$ is also closed.
Let $X$ be a set with cardinality greater than $1$. And let $S \subsetneq X \mid S \neq \emptyset$. You can define a topology on $X$ such that $S$ is open, closed, or neither. Consider the following $4$ examples:
$\tau_1=\{\emptyset,X\}$ $\tau_2=\{\emptyset,S,X\}$, $\tau_3=\{\emptyset,X\setminus S,X\}$ and $\tau_4=\{\emptyset,S,X\setminus S,X\}$.
It is clear that $\tau_i$ is a topology on $X$, $\forall i=1,2,3,4$.
In $\tau_1$, $S$ is neither open nor closed.
In $\tau_2$, $S$ is open but not closed.
In $\tau_3$, $S$ is closed but not open.
In $\tau_4$, $S$ is both open and closed.
If we add the condition for the topology to be metrizable, we can't find examples of metric spaces of cardinality greater than $1$ where certain non empty proper subsets aren't open or aren't closed. Notice that if $X$ is a metrizable topological space, then $X$ is a Fréchet space, i.e., each singleton is closed, and each complementary of a singleton is open.
